# Get "All / 3 days / 7 days / 30 days" in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to reduce multiple queries into a single query, if possible. See:

```
select count(*) ...                           # all
select count(*) ... where timestamp >= {date} # 3 days
select count(*) ... where timestamp >= {date} # 7 days
select count(*) ... where timestamp >= {date} # 30 days
```

Is there a performant way to fetch this with a single query as a single row?

```
All | 3 days | 7 days | 30 days
----|--------|--------|--------
100 | 0      | 70     | 30
```

Comment: Ask yourself how this gets used on the front end: either you've preloaded _all_ the data, and display what's relevant; Or you only load relevant pieces of data at a given time. Those two requirements are satisfied by individual queries (or even a parameterized one based on how many days ago) or by a single query getting all your necessary data. The hybrid between the two isn't needed

Comment: Does it have to be a _single row_ or any _single query_ is fine?

Comment: You can do that with parentahsis around your select and add a SELECT (SELECT CON(*) ....) 'all',(SELECT CON(*) ....) '7,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count) function counts non-NULL values from the expression that you give it so you can calculate your counts with a single query like this:

```
SELECT

    COUNT(*) AS all,
    COUNT( IF (timestamp >= {date03}, 1, NULL) ) AS three_days,
    COUNT( IF (timestamp >= {date07}, 1, NULL) ) AS seven_days,
    COUNT( IF (timestamp >= {date30}, 1, NULL) ) AS thirty_days
    
    ...
```

or simpler still (thanks @David542):

```
SELECT

    COUNT(*) AS all,
    SUM( timestamp >= {date03} ) AS three_days,
    SUM( timestamp >= {date07} ) AS seven_days,
    SUM( timestamp >= {date30} ) AS thirty_days
    
    ...
```

This works because the expression `A >= B` returns either `0` or `1` and so you can just sum the results.

Comment: or could do a `SUM(timestamp >= {date03})`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on a single query but having subqueries inside.
You would not reduce the amout of queries but you would reduce the amount of results.

Following your syntax, it would be somehting like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'All'
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE timestamp >= {date}) AS '3 days'
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE timestamp >= {date}) AS '7 days'
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE timestamp >= {date}) AS '30 days'
FROM YourTable
```